# The PrimaryScrollController is currently attached to more than one ScrollPosition

Tags: flutter, mobile

I have a flutter design using lazyscrollview https://pub.dev/packages/lazy_load_scrollview , on another page, this scroll works fine, but in this design, when scrolling, it gets an error

> "The PrimaryScrollController is currently attached to more than one
> ScrollPosition."

this is my code

```
LazyLoadScrollView(
        onEndOfPage: () {},
        child: Scrollbar(
            child: ListView(
          children: [
            ListView.builder(
                shrinkWrap: true,
                itemCount: 10,
                physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                itemBuilder: (_, i) {
                  return InkWell(
                      onTap: () {},
                      child: Container(
                          height: 200,
                          child: Text("kamu " + i.toString())));
                }),
          ],
        )))
```

Comment: what is the parent of LazyLoadScrollView, is it Scaffold

Comment: i put LazyLoadScrollView at body scaffold

Comment: ok ,why are you using Scrollbar , ListView  .  you can use  ListView.builder as a child of LazyLoadScrollView

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use this way , please change the structure ,it is the best practice

```
Scaffold(
          body: LazyLoadScrollView(
              scrollOffset: 150,
              onEndOfPage: () {
                print('ppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppp');
              },
              child: Scrollbar(
                  child: SingleChildScrollView(
                child: ListView.builder(
                    shrinkWrap: true,
                    itemCount: 10,
                    physics: ClampingScrollPhysics(),
                    itemBuilder: (_, i) {
                      return InkWell(
                          onTap: () {},
                          child: Container(
                              height: 200,
                              child: Text("kamu " + i.toString())));
                    }),
              )))),
```

and adjust the scrollOffset if you want ,

the debug will be

[image]

Comment: without the scrollbar, scroll indicator is not showing

Comment: i am edited the Answer with scrollbar

Comment: you can remove SingleChildScrollView if you want , its  up to your use case